# iphone, when saving image with "renderInContext" to device, the image is blurry?

Tags: iphone, save, photolibrary, blurry

I'm using this code to render an image from view.
Then i am saving it to photo album.
The image is blurry?
Why? Is there a solution?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Tnx all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are propably using a retina device,
Change the following

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size)
```

to

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
```